# Get app icons of installed apps in Flutter from device_apps plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I was figuring out how to display list of installed apps along with their names & icons. Code works well till displaying app names. Here is the right, working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _FirstScreen();
  }
}

class _FirstScreen extends State<FirstScreen>{
  List<Application> apps;
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getApp() async{
    List<Application> _apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true, includeAppIcons: true, includeSystemApps: true);
    setState(() {
      apps = _apps;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getApp();
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: apps.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(apps[index].appName),
            );
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

but when I display app icon in ListTile by:

```
trailing: Icon(Image.memory(apps[index].icon))
```

it gives [icon not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F9gb.png) error.

I even tried **ApplicationWithIcon** class which extends Application class & *icon* defined in it, but it returned [Null Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64kJL.png)

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing

```
List<Application> apps
```

write

```
List apps
```

also, instead of writing

```
List<Application> _apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true, includeAppIcons: true, includeSystemApps: true);
```

write:

```
 List _apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true, includeAppIcons: true, includeSystemApps: true);
```

finally, instead of

```
Icon(Image.memory(apps[index].icon))
```

write

```
Image.memory(apps[index] is ApplicationWithIcon ? app.icon : null)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Icon widget receive a Icons widget and you're passing a Images

ej: `Icon(Icons.home)`

so just pass the image

```
trailing: Image.memory(apps[index].icon)
```

**Update**

you must delete the type and initialize the list:

```
 List apps = [];
```

In your method delete type too

```js
 Future<void> getApp() async{
    List _apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true, 
        includeAppIcons: true, includeSystemApps: true);
      
       setState(() {
         apps = _apps;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Same error [icon not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F9gb.png), & when I try with **ApplicationWithIcon**, then it returns [Null Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64kJL.png) as described above

Comment: here is an example using the same package https://github.com/itamaradin15/list_apps_flutter